# can you use a variable in the message logging policy for host and port?

Tags: api, apigee

can you use a variable in the message logging policy for host and port? for example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<MessageLogging async="false" continueOnError="false" enabled="true" name="splunk">
<Syslog>
<Message>Message. id = {request.header.id}</Message>
<Host>{variable}</Host>
<Port>{variable}</Port>
</Syslog>
</MessageLogging>
```

Answer (score 0):

At this time, the Host and Port entries cannot be variables.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to using variables at runtime is to set those attributes at build time using a build tool like maven.